# Material-UI List (V1-beta): How to pass the list item to onClick function?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have predefined list item in my dumb component. I am trying to pass the list item to my onClick function so my code can recognize which item was clicked and I can navigate accordingly. Here is my code for the dumb component:

```
export const mainMenuListItems = (gn, an, onMenuClick) => (
  <div>
    <ListItem onClick={() => onMenuClick(event, this)} button>
      <ListItemIcon>
        <HomeIcon />
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary="Home" />
    </ListItem>

   <ListItem onClick={() => onMenuClick(event, this)} button>
     <ListItemIcon>
      <ChartIcon />
     </ListItemIcon>
     <ListItemText primary="Charts" />
   </ListItem>
  </div>
);
```

And this is the code for my smart component:

```
  onMenuClick = (event, type) => {
    debugger; //eslint-disable-line
    let a = type; //always undefined
    alert('Home Clicked');
  };
........OTHER CODE............
..............................
  <List className={classes.list}>
    {mainMenuListItems(
      this.props.isGenerationAllowed,
      this.props.isAnalystAllowed,
      this.onMenuClick,
    )}
  </List>
```

I tried to bind "this" in this function call "onMenuClick(event, this)" but no matter what I do, it is always 'undefined'. I am sure it should be pretty easy to access the object where the user has clicked (At least in other languages). Please guide me on how to access the object. I have spent a considerable amount of time on this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your **mainMenuListItems()** is just a regular function here, rather than a component, so **this** will be **undefined**. What information do you need to send via the **onMenuClick()** function?

Comment: Oh, I see. I just need to pass the list item object so I know which item was clicked and I can render a component according to it. So for example, if somebody clicks on the chart, I would like to pass a chart list item and then I will render chart component.

Comment: Do you really need to pass the list item object then? Could you not just pass a string, e.g. 'Home'?

Comment: Thank you for suggestion Steve but I am already passing a string for now. But the thing is there are more than 25 list items in the menu. So I want it to make it dynamic so I don't need to write a lot of code.

Comment: Oh I see. Perhaps look at using **event.target**.

Comment: event.target is "react" object. Thank you for your time and help Steve. I will keep using the string object until I found the solution.